# Problem regarding concept of conservation of angular momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation

Two cylinders of radii r1, and r2 having moments of inertia I1, and I2, about their respective axes. Initially, the cylinders rotate about their axes with angular speeds w1, and w2 as shown in the figure. The cylinders are moved closer to touch each other keeping the axes parallel. The cylinders first slip over each other at the contact but the slipping finally ceases due to the friction between them. Find the angular speeds of the cylinders after the slipping ceases. [image]

I applied conservation of momentum here but I'm unable to obtain the right answer. Taking both cylinders as system, since only friction acts and these forces contribute to internal torques so with absence of external torques I conserved angular momentum of the system but the answer is incorrect.

My question is why cant we conserve angular momentum in such a scenario? How is there external torque and what forces are providing the external torque?

Comment: Hi Ola. Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Are the axles (axes of rotation) constrained to move only along a left/right line? If the answer is yes then there are are external torques acting on the system.

Comment: @Farcher Can you please explain how there are external torques acting on the system

Comment: I just want to know the CONCEPTUAL ERROR of using conservation of angular momentum in this problem, nothing else. Please can you help me with why I can't conserve angular momentum / why is external torque acting on the system and which are these forces contributing to external torque, thats all. My question is only regarding THE CONCEPT.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no forces acting on the axles on the disc then the force diagram is as shown in the left hand diagram with internal frictional force $F_{12}$ and $F_{21}$ acting on the discs.
If the system was like this then as each of the discs has one fore on it the centre of mass of each of the discs will undergo a translational acceleration.

[image]

To stop the centres of mass moving two external force $F_{1E}$ and $F_{2E}$ must act on the discs as shown in the right hand diagram.
Together these two external forces form a external couple and hence an external torque acting on the system of two discs.

Comment: Ok but  acc to diagram, where is any horizontal force for translation here? Wont the normal from the ground = weight of cylinder + friction for first one and for second, normal + friction = weight?

Comment: @Ola I have neglected gravitational forces as they would just add an extra unnecessary complication to the problem or you could think of the discs as being horizontal and you are looking at a plan of the system. The translational motion  in the left hand diagram would be up and down.

Comment: 'or you could think of the discs as being horizontal and you are looking at a plan of the system. The translational motion in the left hand diagram would be up and down' I didnt understand can you please explain again?

Comment: @Ola The up and down refers to the directions as seen on my diagram. The reference to horizontal discs was there to remove the necessity to consider gravitational attraction.

Comment: The discs are already horizontal right. How does that remove the necessity to consider gravity, I'm unable to follow. Horizontal wrt what?

Comment: Okay fine let us neglect gravity. The axle exerts a force on the disc. Now to solve the question, we must take the change in angular momentum of each disc = angular impulse of friction on the corresponding disc = f(r1)(t) = f(r2)(t). I've avoided using the correct signs and other such things but using this concept we obtain right answer as I verified. I just want to discuss the concept . Now why should this work? Why are we considering torque of only tangential force (f here) on each disc while calculating its change in angular momentum? Why not torque of force by axle? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Ola The two forces together are a couple whose torque is force $times$ separation of lines of action of forces so in fact both forces are being considered. The other point is the torque due to a couple is independent of the point about the torque is evaluated.

Comment: Im sorry I didn't quite get you. Lets consider one disc. Now what I'm trying to say here is, torque of friction about axis of rotation =fr; where r = radius of disc. And angular impulse of this force f = frt (assuming f doesnt vary in the interval t) Now what about force exerted by axle? Why arent we including it? Also since axis of rotation is the axle itself , wont torque due to the force by zero and we can conserve angular momentum? I'm sorry but I'm unable to understand what this force is,and how it works,on what it acts,and torque of this force about theaxis. Can you explain again please?

Comment: @Ola Both forces are used to calculate the torque due to a couple. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couple_(mechanics)

Comment: You are taking torque about axis of rotation, correct? So torque of the second force becomes 0 correct? Because it intersects axis of rotation? I know how to calculate torque. I'm asking if the second force intersects the axis , how is there a net torque?

Comment: And I am asking why we aren't including that torque when we write IMPULSE EQUATION? Firstly my question is how is this torque present when we are calculating about axis of rotation , then secondly , to solve this question we write -> fr1(t)=I1(ω1- w1) and fr2(t)=I2(ω2 - w2) and eliminate t and f by dividing and solve for ω1 and ω2 (taking the right signs in the 2 intial equarions) and this gives us our answer. Now where is the torque of the other 2 forces ??? ( by axle) this is my question

Comment: @Ola Your moments of inertia are about the axles hence the torque of the other two forces about the respective axes is zero.

Comment: Exactly, so then why will there be an EXTERNAL torque in the first place ? Because we are calculating everything about the axis itself correct? . Ok if we take both discs as system and centre of any one disc as our point then external torque about the point will not be zero as torque of force on ONLY ONE of the axles is present. Now  we say okay we cannot apply ang momentum which is correct as ext torque not 0. But while writing impulse equation, why is this torque of FORCE ON ONLY ONE of the two AXLES not accounted for? Why are only the tangential forces accounted for?

Comment: @Ola The two external forces acting on the axles form an external couple which can change the angular momentum of the system of two discs.

Comment: Ok I understood. If you take centre of first disk as your point, torque on first disk about the point is fr1 and Angular impulse of this f will be f(r1)(t). Now for second disk , torque will be f(r1) due to friction and f(r1 + r2) in opposite direction due to force BY the axle ON THE DISC( which is equal to f if we NEGLECT GRAVITY only). Hence adding we get a net of f(r2) and angular impulse will be f(r2)(t). I have neglected signs and taken only magnitudes. So this is the analysis right? This can work only if we neglect gravity right and this is the right method to analyze?

Comment: Is that the right way to approach it or am I incorrect?

Comment: @Ola The discs could be horizontal so gravity is not an issue. You look at each disc separately and equate the impulsive torque to the change in angular momentum for each disc as is done in the answer to the question of which this is a duplicate.

Comment: Consider one disc, answer me one thing, does the axle move from its initial position when friction starts acting? Because in another question, a ball moving with speed v at tangent to disc is caught by man standing at edge of the disc. The disc is free to rotate about its centre(only rotate). The disc here is a platform. So obviously some force is being applied by axis of rotation of disc on disc to counter friction from man on disc when he catches the ball and starts moving. The question asked what is angular speed of DISC after he catches ball. Using cons of ang momentum I obtained wrong ans

Comment: However, using impulsive torque due to friction on both (man and ball system)and (disc) I obtained the right answer. But if axis of rotation doesnt move , net EXTERNAL torque WILL BE zero about axis of rotation for the ball+man+ disc system ,hence cons of ang mom can be applied. But if applied I'm obtaining incorrect result. But if the axle moves I can say for sure that I cannot apply cons of ang momentum.so does the axle move?